# Upload de imagem transformando para base64 - laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estou tendo problemas ao receber os dados vindo da minha `View` e transforma-lo para a ***`base 64`***, no `controller` estou fazendo assim:

```
 public function store(ImagemRequest $resquest){
    dd($resquest->all()); //Nest dd aparece ex0.1
    $file = base64_encode($resquest->file('BLOB'));

    dd($file);
    $imagem = Produto::create([
        'CdProduto' => $resquest->CdProduto,
        'NmImagem' => $resquest->NmImagem,
        'DscImagem' => $resquest->DscImagem,
        'BLOB' => $file,
        'FlgPrincipal' => $resquest->FlgPrincipal
    ]);

    session()->flash('flash_message', 'Imagem salva com sucesso');

    $imagens =  Imagem::where('CdProduto', $resquest->CdProduto);
    $produto = Produto::find($resquest->CdProduto);


    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $imagem;
    }else{
        return view('Imagem.listImagem', compact('imagens', 'produto'));
    }
}
```

**Exemplo**

```
array:6 [▼
"_token" => "RiIW0uXbqk1cZ5FGSKTZzQHlDtUoK1sSN2ImHjfW"
  "CdProduto" => "1"
  "NmImagem" => "eqweqwe"
  "DscImagem" => "qweqwe"
  "FlgPrincipal" => "0"
  "BLOB" => "12822161_1045978208829439_1942486736_n.jpg"
]
```

Meu form ta assim:

```
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'imagens.store', 'id' => 'imagens-form']) !!}
        <div class="box-body">
{!! Form::text('CdProduto', $produto->CdProduto, ['class' => 'form-control hidden']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('nmTipoProduto', 'Nome da imagem') !!}
    {!! Form::text('NmImagem', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('dscTipoProduto', 'Descrição da imagem') !!}
    {!! Form::text('DscImagem', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('flgPrincipal', 'Principal ?') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('FlgPrincipal', '1', false, ['class' => 'form-control minimal']) !!}
    {!! Form::label('flgPrincipal', 'Sim') !!}
    {!! Form::radio('FlgPrincipal', '0', true, ['class' => 'form-control minimal']) !!}
    {!! Form::label('flgPrincipal', 'Não') !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::file('BLOB') !!}
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="" />
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit($submitButton, ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}
    {!! link_to_route('imagens.index', 'Voltar', $produto->CdProduto, ['class' =>  'btn btn-warning' ]) !!}
</div>
</div>     
{!! Form::close()  !!}
```

Quero salvar minha imagem em base64 porém no campo Blob só está vindo o nome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para transformar um arquivo de qualquer tipo, vindo de um `input` `type` ***`file`*** utilizando o ***`classe Request`*** presente no [laravel-5](/questions/tagged/laravel-5)

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $file = $request->file('BLOB');
    $name = $file->getPathName();
    $mime = \Storage::mimeType($name);
    $file = base64_encode(file_get_contents($name));
    $src  = 'data: '.$mime.';base64,'.$file;
}
```

o valor da variável `$src` é o que precisa. No seu caso como é uma imagem para fica fácil abrir essa imagem como foi colocado no código.

***Observação:*** *Se a imagem for fixo* na extensão **`jpg`**:

```
$src = 'data: image/jpeg;base64,'.$file;
```

---

*Para carregar a imagem:*

```
<img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" border="0" />
```

---

*Referencias*

- [HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests)
- [finfo_file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.finfo-file.php)
- [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base64-encode.php)
- [fileinfo constants](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.constants.php)
- [Filesystem](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html)

Comment: Como está utilizando Laravel, seria legal usar a função da própria framework para pegar o mimetype. `Storage::mimeType($filename);` pois como o pessoal da Zend gosta de ficar sempre trocando os métodos de nome, assim caso ocorresse a mudança, basta atualizar a framework.

Comment: @PedroSoares, verdade, a edição foi adicionado! correto.